# What color system does flutter use and why do we use `const Color` instead of `new Color`

Tags: dart, flutter

Today I came over following snippet of code that implements gradient in flutter

```
return new Container(
  ...
  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    gradient: new LinearGradient(
      colors: [
        const Color(0xFF3366FF), 
        const Color(0xFF00CCFF),
      ]
      begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
      end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
      stops: [0.0, 1.0],
      tileMode: TileMode.clamp
    ),
  ),
),
```

And it raised 2 questions:

1) What color system is `0xFF3366FF` this? it looks somewhat similar to HEX, but it isn't.

2) Why do we use `const` for `const Color()` opposed to `new Color()` I understand different between both, but const here feels unintuitive for me, I'd expect it to be creating a `new Color()` class instance, similarly to how we use `new Text("Some text")`. If it needs to be const, why isn't `TileMode.clamp` also a const?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the Flutter source

```
class Color {
  /// Construct a color from the lower 32 bits of an [int].
  ///
  /// The bits are interpreted as follows:
  ///
  /// * Bits 24-31 are the alpha value.
  /// * Bits 16-23 are the red value.
  /// * Bits 8-15 are the green value.
  /// * Bits 0-7 are the blue value.
  ///
  /// In other words, if AA is the alpha value in hex, RR the red value in hex,
  /// GG the green value in hex, and BB the blue value in hex, a color can be
  /// expressed as `const Color(0xAARRGGBB)`.
  ///
  /// For example, to get a fully opaque orange, you would use `const
  /// Color(0xFFFF9000)` (`FF` for the alpha, `FF` for the red, `90` for the
  /// green, and `00` for the blue).
  const Color(int value) : value = value & 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

`const` instances are canonicalized.

If you have multiple `const Color(0xFF00CCFF)` in your code, only one instance will be created.

`const` instances are evaluated at compile time.
In the Dart VM this is when the code is loaded, but in Flutter production AoT compilation is used and const values therefore provide a small performance benefit.

See also [How does the const constructor actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744677/how-does-the-const-constructor-actually-work/21746692#21746692)

Comment: The performance gain is not that minimal. Because it allows to use `const` constructor on widgets too ; which will lead to a shortcut in the tree rendering.

Comment: @Darky perhaps. Guessing possible performance gains is difficult. Only benchmarks for concerete use cases are reliable.

Comment: Yeah but in this case, it's the flutter team that recommend const widgets for this exact purpose. Because it will skip the `build` method call. Also : https://youtu.be/dkyY9WCGMi0?t=30m59s

Answer (score 15):

As explained by the accepted answer, `const` constructors are a small optimization.

In dart a `const MyObject(42)` will only be allocated once even when you call it hundreds of time. Which means less memory allocation > faster

---

*But isn't it a negligible optimization ?*

Well, from dart point of view, yes.
But we're in flutter here. We also have a Widget tree that can also use `const` constructors. Which means that we could change your code example to something like this :

```
return const DecoratedBox(
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    gradient: const LinearGradient(
      colors: const [
        const Color(0xFF3366FF), 
        const Color(0xFF00CCFF),
      ],
      begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
      end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
      stops: const [0.0, 1.0],
      tileMode: TileMode.clamp
    ),
  ),
);
```

Here, thanks to `Color` being a constant, we managed to get a constant `LinearGradient`, and ultimately a constant `DecoratedBox` widget.
So not only will the `DecoratedBox` widget be instantiated only once ; but thanks to widgets being immutable ; Flutter will recognize that the widget is the same.

Consequence :

- The whole sub-tree of `DecoratedBox` will be built **once**.
- The associated RenderObject (`RenderDecoratedBox` in this case) will be not be updated at all even when it's parent Container change

This is explained in "Flutter's layered design" video talk. 
[At 31mn](https://youtu.be/dkyY9WCGMi0?t=30m59s) to be exact. But I'd suggest to start the video from [here](https://youtu.be/dkyY9WCGMi0?t=10m45s) to have a bigger understanding of what's skipped.

PS : Some widgets don't have a `const` constructor *at all*. Such as `Container`. But in the case of `Container` you could simply use a `DecoratedBox` instead, which is basically what `Container` use under the hood. The advantage here is that `DecoratedBox` *do* have a const constructor.

Comment: This is awesome information, thank you for the links, will definitely give this a look now! Things like these are what I missed from being mostly in JavaScript environment, it takes out so much knowledge out :/

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppColors {
  static const Color kTransparent = Colors.transparent;
  static const Color kWhite = Colors.white;
  static const Color kBlack = Colors.black;
  static const Color kRed = Colors.red;
  static const Color kRedA = Colors.redAccent;
  static const Color kPink = Colors.pink;
  static const Color kPinkA = Colors.pinkAccent;
  static const Color kBlue = Colors.blue;
  static const Color kBlueA = Colors.blueAccent;
  static const Color kLightBlue = Colors.lightBlue;
  static const Color kLightBlueA = Colors.lightBlueAccent;
  static const Color kGreen = Colors.green;
  static const Color kGreenA = Colors.greenAccent;
  static const Color kLightGreen = Colors.lightGreen;
  static const Color kLightGreenA = Colors.lightGreenAccent;
  static const Color kLime = Colors.lime;
  static const Color kLimeA = Colors.limeAccent;
  static const Color kGrey = Colors.grey;
  static const Color kBlueGrey = Colors.blueGrey;
  static const Color kPurple = Colors.purple;
  static const Color kPurpleA = Colors.purpleAccent;
  static const Color kDeepPurple = Colors.deepPurple;
  static const Color kDeepPurpleA = Colors.deepPurpleAccent;
  static const Color kIndigo = Colors.indigo;
  static const Color kIndigoA = Colors.indigoAccent;
  static const Color kYellow = Colors.yellow;
  static const Color kYellowA = Colors.yellowAccent;
  static const Color kOrange = Colors.orange;
  static const Color kOrangeA = Colors.orangeAccent;
  static const Color kDeepOrange = Colors.deepOrange;
  static const Color kDeepOrangeA = Colors.deepOrangeAccent;
  static const Color kAmber = Colors.amber;
  static const Color kAmberA = Colors.amberAccent;
  static const Color kCyan = Colors.cyan;
  static const Color kCyanA = Colors.cyanAccent;
  static const Color kTeal = Colors.teal;
  static const Color kTealA = Colors.tealAccent;
  static const Color kBrown = Colors.brown;
}
```