# Flutter variable with const keyword

Tags: dart, flutter

In the 'Write Your First App' tutorial on the Flutter docs, Step 4 titled "Step 4: Create an infinite scrolling ListView", you are asked to create 2 variables show here:

```
class RandomWordsState extends State<RandomWords> {
  final _suggestions = <WordPair>[];

  final _biggerFont = const TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0);
  ...
}
```

Why is the `const` keyword used in the 3rd line?  I come from a C# and JavaScript background and I'm not used to seeing this on the right side of an assignment statement.  I notice if I remove it it still works as I expected. Could you please explain **in lamens terms** why this is being used and when should I do the same?  I'm guessing it's overkill and I don't have to use it but I just want to make sure.

I do not believe this is a duplicate because the answer in this post was perfect in explaining my question and not found in the other post, not to mention the other post is a two part question that nobody would find when using google.

Comment: [what is the difference in between ''const'' and ''final'' keyword in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50431055/608639)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From dart news website:

> "`const`" has a meaning that's a bit more complex and subtle in Dart.
>   const modifies *values*. You can use it when creating collections,
>   like `const [1, 2, 3]`, and when constructing objects (instead of new)
>   like `const Point(2, 3)`. Here, const means that the object's entire
>   deep state can be determined entirely at compile time and that the
>   object will be frozen and completely immutable.

[Read more here.](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html)

In my words, you can use `const` constructor(constructors that defined as `const`) like `const Text()` or `new Text()`.

If you use `const Text()`: This will allocate only one memory space and when you are add another `const Text()`, that will reuse the same object but the `new Text()` will always allocate new memory space. So, using `const` you can increase your program performance(not that much performance but less memory allocation). Also, you can define your class constructors as `const`, if it need to reuse.

> I notice if I remove it it still works as I expected.

That because with Dart two `new` and `const` keyword optional when you are creating object/instance, that will handle by the Dart VM. Initially there was some problems but those are fixed now.

Even if you avoid `const`/`new` those will added by the [Dart VM](https://www.dartlang.org/dart-vm/tools/dart-vm). The reason for to made those two keyword optional is in Flutter you have to type those two everywhere(ex: in widget tree).

[Dart two enhancement() Feb 23](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-80ba01f43b6)

Comment: I just found the best explanation for this question [HERE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLSG_Wh_YWc&t=11438s)

Comment: It's just annoying. For example in Flutter classes like PopupMenuButton are painful to edit because of this.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another question with some answers that might help.

[What color system does flutter use and why do we use `const Color` instead of `new Color`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996420/what-color-system-does-flutter-use-and-why-do-we-use-const-color-instead-of-n)

> As explained by the accepted answer, const constructors are a small optimization.
>   In dart a const MyObject(42) will only be allocated once even when you call it hundreds of time. Which means less memory allocation > faster

Comment: Consider flagging as duplicate instead of such answer

Comment: Also, `const` with widgets has a different behavior specific to widgets (that colors don't have)

Answer (score 3):

Const means that the object's entire deep state can be determined entirely at compile time and that the object will be frozen and completely immutable.