# error: The values in a const list literal must be constants. Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, material-design, flutter-widget

[can any one tell me why is there an error. im a beginner in flutter. can any one help.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtpeN.png)

this is the code, the error is on the onpressed fucntion.

```
Expanded(
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage('images/dice1.png'),
                    )
                  ),
    
                ),
    
              ),
```

error:

```
error: Invalid constant value. (invalid_constant at line 3)
error: The values in a const list literal must be constants. (non_constant_list_element at line 3)
```

Comment: Remove the const keyword you've written near to row children

Comment: thank you @MidhunMP Can You please tell me why, because the it worked after removing the const keyword.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576209/flutter-variable-with-const-keyword/51576842

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the const keyword if you are not using fixed values. Flutter uses the const keyword as an indicator for a widget to never rebuild as it will get evaluated at compile time and only once.