# Flutter: The values in a const list literal must be constants. Try removing the keyword 'const' from the list literal

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

Here is the Widget that is getting the error:
**The values in a const list literal must be constants. Try removing the keyword 'const' from the list literal.**

```
ResponsiveCenter(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: ResponsiveCenterEdgeInsets.horizontal,
                    vertical: ResponsiveCenterEdgeInsets.vertical),
                child: PrimaryButton(
                    text: 'Weight',
                    isLoading: false,
                    **onPressed: () => context.pushNamed(AppRoute.weightHistory.name))**) // <-this code is throwing the error
```

Here is the "PrimaryButton" widget:

```
class PrimaryButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const PrimaryButton(
      {super.key, required this.text, this.isLoading = false, this.onPressed});
  final String text;
  final bool isLoading;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        child: ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0)),
            onPressed: onPressed,
            child: isLoading
                ? const CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )
                : Text(
                    text,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  )));
  }
}
```

Here is the "AppRouter" widget:

```
enum AppRoute { home, weightHistory, zoneInfo }

final goRouterProvider = Provider<GoRouter>((ref) {
  return GoRouter(initialLocation: '/', debugLogDiagnostics: true, routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      name: AppRoute.home.name,
      builder: (context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/weightHistory',
      name: AppRoute.weightHistory.name,
      builder: (context, state) => const WeightHistoryScreen(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: '/zoneInfo',
      name: AppRoute.zoneInfo.name,
      builder: (context, state) => const ZoneInfoScreen(),
    )
  ]);
});
```

There is no "const" in the error'd code. What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems like the error is being thrown by the ```ResponsiveCenter``` widget which is using a const list for its child property but the ```PrimaryButton``` widget passed as a child is not a constant due to its ```onPressed``` property being a closure that is not a constant. Did try removing the const keyword from the ```ResponsiveCenter``` widget and see if that resolves the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: The values in a const list literal must be constants. Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69535830/error-the-values-in-a-const-list-literal-must-be-constants-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

I realized my problem, the "const" declaration was further up the Widget tree, declaring "Scaffold" const.