# What is the reason for the blue underline? Flutter

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, underline

Does anyone know the reason for the blue lines??

When I double the size variable, the blue underlines turn into red underlines.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's from linter. It suggests you to add const keyword for those widgets.

Comment: Do classes have to be const? i am new to this language. When I don't const the classes the app works but the blue underlines are annoying

Comment: Check this answer to get an idea about use of const: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576209/flutter-variable-with-const-keyword/51576842

Answer (score 3):

It's a linter warning. Usually it tells you about the best practices that can improve your code quality.

In this case, it is asking you to use const keyword for those widgets while initialising. The exact rule for this warning can be found here: [prefer_const_constructors](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/prefer_const_constructors.html).

You can check all the linter rules [here](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/)

Answer (score 0):

it just tells you if you do this your code would work better or would be more readable.
in this case, adding const to your Icon would make this widget not to rebuild completely from scratch and use data that have been stored in ram

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm new so I couldn't rate your answer