# In Consumer builder, is there any different between using child and const?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I known that child argument is use to tell builder to not re-build that widget every time data change.

But isn't that the defenition of const? why not use const instead.

```
Consumer<String>(
  builder: (context, value, child) => Badge(
    child: const IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
    badgeContent: Text(value),
  ),
)
```

vs

```
Consumer<String>(
  builder: (context, value, child) => Badge(
    child: child,
    badgeContent: Text(value),
  ),
  child: IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_bag),
    onPressed: () {},
  )
)
```

Is there any different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter variable with const keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51576209/flutter-variable-with-const-keyword)

Comment: thanks, but no. My question is what the different using child and const widget in Consumer.

Comment: I already got awnser from nagendra nag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever widget you pass as a child will not rebuild when data is changed.

You can avoid unnecessary rebuilding of widgets using child.

Whether it is a const Widget or a normal Widget when you keep it in the child then the widget won't rebuild when changes occur.

Comment: so, the advantage of child is that it don't have to be const to not rebuild every time the value on provider change, mean that child still can change from other source?

Comment: didn't get it what you are trying to ask....can you please ask more specifically?

Comment: both child and const are not rebuild when data change, but child can rebuild by other source. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. you are right.