# InputDecoration errorText must be constant

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton

[[dart] Invalid constant value.
[dart] Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPYXG.png)

I want to make DropdownButton , but errorText only accept constant variable.

```
[dart] Invalid constant value.
[dart] Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.
```

Constant variable means I cannot replace with other text.


Maybe any other way to make DropdownButton validation?

```
String errorGender = null;

    var _inputGender = InputDecorator(
      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Gender', errorText: errorGender),
      isEmpty: data['gender'] == null,
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: ButtonTheme(
          alignedDropdown: true,
            child: DropdownButton(
              isDense: true,
              value: data['gender'],
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() => data['gender'] = value),
              items: _gender.map((value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value[0].toUpperCase() + value.substring(1)),
                );
              }).toList()
            )
        )
      )
    );
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Remove `const` before `InputDecoration`

```
decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Gender', errorText: errorGender)
```

Comment: It works. But can you explain the meaning of 'const'? What is the difference between const and no const?

Comment: Keyword `const` create only one instance of this field to whole application. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47996512/7130820