# dart Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions

Tags: dart, flutter

When developing app with flutter, i want to define some common styles.

The code is as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class AppStyle {
  static Color colorRed = const Color(0xffe04f5f);
  static Color colorWhite = const Color(0xffffffff);
  static Color colorGreen = const Color(0xff1abc9c);
}
```

Now, i want to define a new style.

```
static TextStyle listRowTitle = const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: colorGreen);
```

If you write to the above, then colorGreen will have a problem here. The wrong message is

```
[dart] Invalid constant value.
[dart] Arguments of a constant creation must be constant expressions.
Color colorGreen
```

If you change colorGreen to Color (0xff1abc9c), there is no problem!

```
static TextStyle listRowTitle = const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Color(0xff1abc9c));
```

Ask me to teach me，please!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, colors are defined in a class you have to do something like below:

```
AppStyle.colorGreen
```

**Udate:**

Ohh, I see, you are using `cont TextStyle`. So, you can remove `const` or add `const` for your `AppStyle`.

I simply removed the `const` from `TextStyle`:

```
TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: AppStyle.colorGreen)
```

[Understand how `const` works.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744677/how-does-the-const-constructor-actually-work/21746692#21746692)

Comment: Thank you for your answer，and  i tried like you, but there are have a problem。static TextStyle listRowTitle = const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: AppStyle.colorGreen);       The error message ：[dart] Invalid constant value.
class AppStyle

Comment: Thank you. My problem has been solved. I think I should go deeper into the grammar of dart.   Finally, can you help me explain why?

Comment: @sunmoon you have to understand `const` and `new` read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996420/what-color-system-does-flutter-use-and-why-do-we-use-const-color-instead-of-n

Comment: The problem is you are declaring a variable value (colorGreen) to a property (color) of a constant widget. Constant widgets cannot vary, change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are declaring a variable value (colorGreen) to a property (color) of a constant widget. Constant widgets cannot vary, change.

Just remove the modifier **const** from your widget

```
static TextStyle listRowTitle = const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: colorGreen);
```