# const variable must be initialized with a constant value || const vs var || flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, constants

```
    const kBorderStyle2 = BoxDecoration(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
    Radius.circular(20),
  ),
  border: Border.all(color: Colors.greenAccent,),
);
```

Hi,
I've been learning flutter on my own and got stuck on this error.
I have a constants.dart file where I am saving all the styles for the app.
Whenever I try to add the `color: Colors.greenAccent,` to the const, I get an error "const variable must be initialized with a constant value."
but then I change const to var and the problem goes away.

I also get the same error for the following code:

```
const kBorderStyleX = BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.greenAccent,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
);
```

This goes away when I change it to:

```
const kBorderStyle1 = BoxDecoration(
  color: Colors.greenAccent,
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
    Radius.circular(20),
  ),
);
```

Is there something I am missing with const?
Any reason why I am getting the error?

Comment: As far as your confusion regarding `const Colors.greenAccent` is considered. Then the constructor from `Flutter` comes with `const` itself. Refer to the link below you will get some more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47996420/what-color-system-does-flutter-use-and-why-do-we-use-const-color-instead-of-n

Answer (score 2):

To check whether an object is eligible to be assigned to a `const` variable, Dart relies on the constructor that created the object, which can be marked as const or not (e.g. `const BorderRadius.all()` vs. `BorderRadius.circular()`).

This is why even though an object may even not be able to be changed, Dart can treat it as it could, if the used constructor is not marked as `const`.

Comment: Links to the docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BorderRadius-class.html, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Border-class.html

Comment: `Border.all()` is also an issue in the OP's first example.