# Default values of an optional parameter must be constant

Tags: dart

I've been trying to get this right for some time and can't figure out what is wrong.

```
enum MyEnum { a, b }

class ClassA {
  final MyEnum myEnum;
  ClassA({this.myEnum = MyEnum.a});
}

class ClassB {
  final ClassA classA;
  ClassB({this.classA = ClassA()}); // ClassA expression is underlined with red
}
```

The IDE (Visual Studio Code) complains with:

```
[dart] Default values of an optional parameter must be constant.
```

I've tried to prefix it with `const`, `new`, and passing values to the `ClassA` constructor, but nothing works. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try

```
enum MyEnum { a, b }

class ClassA {
  final MyEnum myEnum;
  ClassA({this.myEnum});
}

class ClassB {
  final ClassA classA;
  ClassB({this.classA}); // ClassA expression is underlined with red
}
```

no need for '=' operator. It will automatically assign the value when you will pass it to the constructor.

Use the '=' operator only when you need to pass a default value to your variables hence, making them optional parameters.

**Edit**

```
enum MyEnum { a, b }

class ClassA {
  final MyEnum myEnum;
  const ClassA({this.myEnum = MyEnum.a});
}

class ClassB {
  final ClassA classA;
  ClassB({this.classA = const classA()}); // ClassA expression is underlined with red
}
```

This is the only way i could find to achieve what you want, the constructor should be default

This is called a [canonicalized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744677/how-does-the-const-constructor-actually-work) constructor.

Comment: Won't I then need to supply value for classA when I instantiate ClassB? I.e. wont I need to do

var classB = ClassB(classA: ClassA())

instead of

var classB = ClassB()

Comment: Yes you have to supply value for A whenever you instantiate B this way, I’ll try to find a workaround. By the way, it is said that no class should instantiate other class but it should get its dependencies from external sources for modularity and high cohesion.

Comment: Yes its similar to the first answer, I think that might be the only way, even I still don't quite understand this whole "canoncialized" thing. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 14):

For `ClassA` to be able to create constant values, the constructor must be marked as const.

```
enum MyEnum { a, b }

class ClassA {
  final MyEnum myEnum;
  const ClassA({this.myEnum = MyEnum.a});  // <- constructor is const.
}

class ClassB {
  final ClassA classA;
  ClassB({this.classA = const ClassA()}); // <- creation is const
}
```

You need to write `const` for the object creation, even if only constant values are allowed as default values. The language do not automatically insert a `const` in that position because the language team wants to reserve the option of allowing non-constant default values at some point.

Comment: Thank you, but isn't a const class a whole different thing; a type that has a known canonical value at compile time and is usable in switch statements, etc.? The only thing I am really trying to do here is creating an instance of the class with default values. Is that just not possible in Dart?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "const class". Classes may have `const` constructors, which allows them to create const *values* (then the class also has to have only final fields). Constant values are canonicalized, but you can create non-constant values - it's not a property of the class, but of the way you create the individual values. Parameter default values must be const values. So, if you want a default value of type `ClassA`, then `ClassA` must have a const constructor (and only final fields, which it already does).

Comment: "Parameter default values must be const values" @Irn any idea why?

Answer (score 14):

If the Order date wasn't specified, use DateNow..
If the Order date was specified, use it.

```
class Order  {
  final String id;
  final double amount;
  final List cartItems;
  final DateTime? dateTime;

  Order(
      {required this.id,
      required this.amount,
      required this.cartItems,
       dateTime
       })
      :this.dateTime = ( dateTime != null ? dateTime : DateTime.now() );
}


void main() {
  
  var order_use_default_date = Order(id:"1",amount:1000,cartItems:[1,2,3]);
  var order_use_param_date = Order(id:"1",amount:1000,cartItems:[1,2,3],dateTime:DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 2)) );
  
  print(order_use_default_date.dateTime);
  print(order_use_param_date.dateTime);
  
  
}
```

Comment: at the end of the constructor, i'd rather write 
`: dateTime = dateTime ?? DateTime.now()`
which would be enough

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried?

```
class ClassB {
  final ClassA _classA;
  ClassB({ClassA classA}): _classA = classA ?? ClassA();
}
```

Suppose let's say you want to set empty list as a default value for a list member, adding 'const' to that default value, will prevent any actions like add() etc. In that case you can use

```
class A{
  List<int> numbers;

// will raise : Uncaught Error: Unsupported operation: add
// when you call the addEle() method
//   A({this.numbers= const []});  
    A({var passedNumbers}) : this.numbers = passedNumbers??[];
    void addEle(int n){
      numbers.add(n);
    
  }
  }

void main() {
  
  var obj = A();
  obj.addEle(5);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use of initializer list

Don't define the parameter in the constructor but rather **in the initializer list**:

```
enum MyEnum { a, b }

class ClassA { // a non constant class
  final MyEnum myEnum;
  ClassA({this.myEnum = MyEnum.a});
}

class ClassB {
  final ClassA classA;
  ClassB({ClassA? classA}) : classA = classA ?? ClassA(); //init in initalizer list
}
```

Also, make sure to check if you can [make your ClassA a constant class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51907867/11003497) as already described.