# Default values of an optional parameter must be constant flutter / dart

Tags: class, flutter, dart, constructor

I'm trying to organize some Site class data in an Event class, but I'm getting a "The default value of an optional parameter must be constant" and I've been struggling with this for a while now.

I found this: [Default values of an optional parameter must be constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907159/default-values-of-an-optional-parameter-must-be-constant), but I'm having a hard time connecting the specifics of that example with my code.

My intention was to use the Site class to do a lookup of all the pertinent site data (address, phone, etc) in the Site constructor, and then store that within the Event class as it's own parameter... but I'm not sure the best way to do this.

Here's the code:

```
class Event {
  // passed
  final TimeOfDay earliestTime;
  final DateTime startTime;
  final String siteName;

  Site siteInfo;

  Event(
      {
      @required this.earliestTime,
      @required this.startTime,
      @required this.siteName,
      this.siteInfo = Site(siteName)} //<-- "Site(siteName) is underlined in red with the
                                      // non_constant_default_value error
      ) { }
}


class Site {
  String siteName;
  Site(String siteName) {
    this.siteName = "Site 1";  //<-- my attempt at a default value
    int index = sites.indexOf(siteName); 
    phone = phones[index];
    addressStreet = addressStreets[index];
  }

  String addressStreet;
  String phone;
}

List<String> sites = [  // <-- Site lookup table
  "Site 1",
  "Site 2",
];


List<String> phones = [  // <-- use index to get values
  "(312)857-5309",
  "(773)857-5310",
];

List<String> addressStreets = [
  "123 Bear St.",
  "234 Elk St.",
];
```

In short, what is the error, and how would I be able to use the Site class as a way to hold all of the site data within the Event class?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> ```dart
>   Event({
>     @required this.earliestTime,
>     @required this.startTime,
>     @required this.siteName,
>     this.siteInfo = Site(siteName)
>   }) {}
> ```

You're specifying that if something constructs an `Event` object but omits the `siteInfo` argument, the `Event` constructor should initialize `siteInfo` to a default value of `Site(siteName)`.  However, Dart requires that default argument values be compile-time constants, and `Site(siteName)` cannot be determined at compilation time since it depends on `siteName`.

In general, you instead can let the default value be `null` and initialize it later, either via an initialization list:

```dart
  Event({
    @required this.earliestTime,
    @required this.startTime,
    @required this.siteName,
    Site siteInfo
  }) : siteInfo = siteInfo ?? Site(siteName) {}
```

or within the constructor body.

That said, it's not clear to me that you actually want `Event` to have both `siteName` and `siteInfo` parameters.  Is it okay if the supplied `siteName` is different from `siteInfo.siteName`?  If not, then the `Event` constructor should require that only one is provided to eliminate any possibility of inconsistency, e.g.:

```dart
  Event({
    @required this.earliestTime,
    @required this.startTime,
    @required this.siteName,
  }) : siteInfo = Site(siteName) {}
```

or

```dart
  Event({
    @required this.earliestTime,
    @required this.startTime,
    @required this.siteInfo
  }) {}

  String get siteName => siteInfo.siteName;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be setting your option parameter '=' to there is no need for it so I would try this.

```
class Event {
  // passed
  final TimeOfDay earliestTime;
  final DateTime startTime;
  final String siteName;

  Site siteInfo;

  Event(
      {
      @required this.earliestTime,
      @required this.startTime,
      @required this.siteName,
      this.siteInfo, //<-- "Site(siteName) is underlined in red with the
      }                      // non_constant_default_value error
      );
}
```

`Site(siteName)` would go in the instantiation of `Event(... siteInfo: Site(siteName));`

```
class Foo {
  String word;
  Foo({this.word});
}

class Phoo {
  Foo foo = Foo(word: 'A Word');
  Phoo();
}

 print(Phoo().foo.word);
```

Comment: of course... make the class, then insert it.  Out of curiosity... is it even possible to create a class within a class? (like I was trying to do?)

Comment: What I print above would be acceptable. So yes you can Instantiate one class inside another.