# Dart class optional constructor parameter with default value leads to error

Tags: dart

I'm new to Dart and coming from TypeScript I'm struggling to wrap my head around the following error:

> The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.

For this code:

```
class Counter {
  int base;
  List<dynamic> bonus;

  Counter({this.base = 0, this.bonus = []}); // Error here

  // omitted counter methods
}

class OffensiveAttributes {
  Counter oneHanded;

  OffensiveAttributes(
      {this.oneHanded = Counter(base: 0)}); // And error here
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is when a new `OffensiveAttributes` instance is created, you should be able to have `base` set to `2` for example. Of course I could do this:

```
Counter oneHanded = Counter(base: 0);

OffensiveAttributes(
      {this.oneHanded});
```

But if `oneHanded` isn't passed in when the instance is created, I end up with a value of `null`  which I don't want.

If I try adding `const` and `final` in the `Counter` I get stuck when I need to change the `base` value using `add` or `subtract` methods for example.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default values of an optional parameter must be constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51907159/default-values-of-an-optional-parameter-must-be-constant)

Comment: @Mattia No, I looked at that question but I still don't understand how to change my code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56489812/.

Comment: @jamesdlin Thanks! That solved it. Also read https://medium.com/flutter-community/deconstructing-dart-constructors-e3b553f583ef which gave me some insight in what the different syntaxes are called and how they're used.

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to pass const [] as given below

```
class Counter {
  int base;
  List<dynamic> bonus;

  Counter({this.base = 0, this.bonus = const[]}); 

  // omitted counter methods
}
```

Comment: And what to do about `Counter`?