# Dart Class with ":" vs Dart Class without

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm quite confused regarding Dart Constructors.
What I am trying to do is having two parameters, both **final** but one is based on the other.

```
class Chart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> _recentTransactions;
  final double _totalAmount;
  Chart(List<Transaction> _recentTransactions)
      : this._recentTransactions = _recentTransactions,
        this._totalAmount =
            _recentTransactions.fold(0.0, (prev, next) => prev + next.price);
}
```

This code above works. I have a private list, and my private double `_totalAmount` is final but is based on the list `_recentTransaction`.

I've came up with this code reading the [Documentation for final constructor](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors)

But I don't really understand why this won't work

```
class Chart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Transaction> _recentTransactions;
  final double _totalAmount;
  Chart(List<Transaction> _recentTransactions) {
    this._recentTransactions = _recentTransactions;
    this._totalAmount =
        _recentTransactions.fold(0.0, (prev, next) => prev + next.price);
  }
}
```

The difference pretty much is that on first implementation I use the `:`, and in second a normal `{}`

What am I missing here? As much as I understood the `:` is used to refer to a different constructor (that in this case I don't have).

I could also make the second example works not declaring **final** the _totalAmount, still, since the value won't ever change (and plus, since is in Flutter, I got a warning regarding that I should declare it final because my class extends a StatelessWidget that is declered as @immutable.

TL;DR: Why I can use a Constructor with `:` for final parameters but it doesn't work with a normal Constructor?

Comment: have you check this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/52528818/7666442

Comment: Ok. It can be marked as duplicated, sorry :/