# How do I get this official Flutter ListView sample to scroll on iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, listview, scroll

I want to create a scrollable ListView in a Flutter app. I tried copying sample code that uses ListView from [this tutorial](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui#bringing-it-all-together). I modified the list of items to make it longer than the screen. It is scrollable in the browser when using the embedded version in the tutorial, but it does not scroll when I build an iOS app (using Visual Studio Code) and test it in an iOS simulator.

Here is my modified code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Product {
  const Product({required this.name});

  final String name;
}

typedef CartChangedCallback = Function(Product product, bool inCart);

class ShoppingListItem extends StatelessWidget {
  ShoppingListItem({
    required this.product,
    required this.inCart,
    required this.onCartChanged,
  }) : super(key: ObjectKey(product));

  final Product product;
  final bool inCart;
  final CartChangedCallback onCartChanged;

  Color _getColor(BuildContext context) {
    // The theme depends on the BuildContext because different
    // parts of the tree can have different themes.
    // The BuildContext indicates where the build is
    // taking place and therefore which theme to use.

    return inCart //
        ? Colors.black54
        : Theme.of(context).primaryColor;
  }

  TextStyle? _getTextStyle(BuildContext context) {
    if (!inCart) return null;

    return const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black54,
      decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: () {
        onCartChanged(product, inCart);
      },
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: _getColor(context),
        child: Text(product.name[0]),
      ),
      title: Text(
        product.name,
        style: _getTextStyle(context),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ShoppingList extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShoppingList({required this.products, super.key});

  final List<Product> products;

  // The framework calls createState the first time
  // a widget appears at a given location in the tree.
  // If the parent rebuilds and uses the same type of
  // widget (with the same key), the framework re-uses
  // the State object instead of creating a new State object.

  @override
  State<ShoppingList> createState() => _ShoppingListState();
}

class _ShoppingListState extends State<ShoppingList> {
  final _shoppingCart = <Product>{};

  void _handleCartChanged(Product product, bool inCart) {
    setState(() {
      // When a user changes what's in the cart, you need
      // to change _shoppingCart inside a setState call to
      // trigger a rebuild.
      // The framework then calls build, below,
      // which updates the visual appearance of the app.

      if (!inCart) {
        _shoppingCart.add(product);
      } else {
        _shoppingCart.remove(product);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Shopping List'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
        children: widget.products.map((product) {
          return ShoppingListItem(
            product: product,
            inCart: _shoppingCart.contains(product),
            onCartChanged: _handleCartChanged,
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    title: 'Shopping App',
    home: ShoppingList(
      products: [
        Product(name: 'Eggs'),
        Product(name: 'Flour'),
        Product(name: 'Chocolate chips'),
        Product(name: 'Chocolate chips'),
        Product(name: 'Chocolate chips'),
        Product(name: 'Chocolate chips'),
        Product(name: 'Chocolate chips'),
        Product(name: 'Chocolate chips'),
        Product(name: 'Chocolate chips'),
        Product(name: 'Chocolate chips'),
        Product(name: 'Chocolate chips'),
        Product(name: 'Chocolate chips'),
        Product(name: 'Chocolate chips'),
        Product(name: 'Chocolate chips'),
        Product(name: 'Chocolate chips'),
      ],
    ),
  ));
}
```

Comment: Hello, you could try to add in your listview : `const BouncingScrollPhysics(parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actually issue is not a scrolling issue, because that would work perfectly fine.

Your issue should be visible in the console:

```
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 259 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
```

This is because you're using `ObjectKey(product)` (which is perfectly fine) together with a `const` constructor in your material app:

```dart
runApp(const MaterialApp(
```

This way, all your list items will also be constructed as const. Since you have multiple times the same product in your cart (`Chocolate chips`) you generate the exact same object key multiple times, so the error arises. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744677/how-does-the-const-constructor-actually-work) answer for more information how const works in Flutter.

So, to solve you can two things:

1. Remove `const`, so each product will have its own identity.
2. Make sure for testing you have distinct items in your card.

Comment: Thanks, @manuel-rauber! I didn't see the error in the console, but I think it was because I ran it in the debugger and I had breakpoint for uncaught exceptions enabled. It stopped on the exception this exact exception. When I add distinct keys it doesn't throw that exception.

Comment: Also, it was also partly user error -- I wasn't using the correct gesture to scroll in the iOS Simulator. :-/